# Background color theme problems

Tags: android, background-color, android-theme

I have a problem with background on activities and fragments when I use background in App theme:

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
```

When I put this on my theme and navigate between fragments with animation make a strange shadow:

[image]

This is normal?
I have a transaction animation between fragments:

```
//add fragment
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(
    R.anim.enter,
    R.anim.exit,
    R.anim.pop_enter,
    R.anim.pop_exit
).replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragmentToShow)
 .addToBackStack(null).commit()
```

If I remove the animation fragment, shadow overlap previous fragment (is worst then the animation is not the problem):

[image]

All base theme app is:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.App" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:color/transparent</item>

    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/secondaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>


    <!-- Styles of text -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorText</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_regular</item>

    <!-- CheckBox style -->
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/MyCheckBoxStyle</item>

    <!-- styles of button -->
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>

</style>
```

The shadows disappear after seconds in both cases...
Can you help me, please?

Comment: Try to remove colorControlNormal and android:colorBackground if it will help for you

Comment: Same error nothing change.

Comment: Are you try to add background color  white in both fragment?

Comment: obviously, if I try to add this color in the theme is to prevent ad this color in 2000 fragments

Comment: can you try to setTranslationZ() to 0 in onViewCreated method of next fragment to be opened . As per the android developer docs i feel elevation and Translationz are responsible for the view shadow.

Answer (score 0):

> If I remove the animation fragment, shadow overlap previous fragment (is worst then the animation is not the problem):

I had the same issue with one of my old app. I found the issue was with fragments, they have a transparent background. You have to set the background color to fragments to stop them by showing previous `activity or fragment` contents.

Try doing

```
fragment.getView().setBackgroundColor(YOUR COLOR CHOICE);
```

[maybe this can also help you out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49127639/12768925)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

apply background color white to your fragment's parent layout